# Twitter app is not getting started

Tags: r, twitter, roauth

I have written following script to extract tweets from twitter.

```
library("twitteR")
library("ROAuth")
library("RCurl")
library("httr")
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",destfile="cacert.pem")
ck <- '4QPOQJoiBgoGP7jU13Akxfp2E'
cs <- 'ued02VUpial3K8NW8foectZj1UFtsEfQetQJbYXD21uCj0ohJc'
ak <- '136316586-xWnCMrE5UYSzigTOwTVyR4NH4gfR01adpR5SF5IK'
as <- 'zsIj4lsDc5xKcDyofWkYijKnUY8Uj71sg1NfaIFKZbGc2'
reqURL<- 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
acURL <- 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
auURL <- 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize'
cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=ck,consumerSecret=cs,requestURL=reqURL,accessURL=acURL,authURL=auURL)
cred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")
save(cred, file="twitter_authentication.Rdata")
load("twitter_authentication.Rdata")
oauth_endpoints("twitter")
myapp <- oauth_app("twitter",key=ck,secret=cs)
twitter_token <- oauth1.0_token(oauth_endpoints("twitter"), myapp)
setup_twitter_oauth(ck,cs)
search.string <- "#Bahubali"
no.of.tweets <- 10
tweets <- searchTwitter(search.string, n=no.of.tweets, lang="en")
tweets
write.csv(tweets, file='/home/horopter/tweet/CSVTweets.csv', row.names=F)
```

However I get this
setup_twitter_oauth(ck,cs)
[1] "Using browser based authentication"
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort

and I get stuck there. website either says 'You do not have permissions.' or doesn't open at all.
If I don't give a callback url, it doesn't authenticate, otherwise gets stuck again as aforementioned. Help me out here.

Comment: Try doing it from an R console vs RStudio.

Comment: I tried the whole thing in R console only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used tried using the same code and authentication token and here is the code that worked for me. The `setup_twitter_oauth` requires all `ck, cs, ak, as` arguments.

```
library("twitteR")
library("ROAuth")
library("RCurl") 
library("httr")
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",destfile="cacert.pem")
ck <- '4QPOQJoiBgoGP7jU13Akxfp2E'
cs <- 'ued02VUpial3K8NW8foectZj1UFtsEfQetQJbYXD21uCj0ohJc'
ak <- '136316586-xWnCMrE5UYSzigTOwTVyR4NH4gfR01adpR5SF5IK'
as <- 'zsIj4lsDc5xKcDyofWkYijKnUY8Uj71sg1NfaIFKZbGc2'
setup_twitter_oauth(ck,cs, ak, as)
search.string <- "#Bahubali"
```

This should setup your authentication once you have downloaded the `.pem` file.
When it asks for authentication press 1.

Comment: `[1] "Using direct authentication"
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'`

Comment: Guys, how do I convert data frame to status object?

Comment: Sorry @SantoshKumarDesai didn't get your question? have you been able to setup the OAuth?

Comment: Yes I could setup Oauth, although logging in by setup_twitter_oauth() each time feels cumbersome. I stored retrieved tweets in a csv file by converting them from status object to data.frame.  I'm unable to retrieve tweets from csv. I wanted to do 
`for( i in 1:3 )
{
 ch <- toString(i)
 ch <- paste(ch,".csv",sep="")
 if(i==1)
  B <- read.csv(ch,sep=',')
 else
  B <- rbind(B, read.csv(ch,sep=','))
}
Bscore <- as.matrix(apply(B[, -1], 1, function(r) paste(names(B)[-1], r, sep=":", collapse=" ")))
Bscore <- laply(B, function(t) t$getText())`

Comment: It results in Error in t$getText : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. What can I do to retrieve my tweets from csv? I can provide data if you need more info.